# matplotlib hatched and filled histograms

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I would like to make histograms that are both hatched and filled (like these bar plots on the left in this [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html)):

[image: hatched_plot]

Here's the code I tried to use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(values, bins, histtype='step', linewidth=2, facecolor='c', hatch='/')
```

But no matter whether I specify "facecolor" or "color", only the lines of the hatching appear in colour and the histogram is still unfilled. How can I make the hatching show up on top of a filled histogram?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In order to fill the area below the histogram the kwarg `fill` can be set to `True`. Then, the facecolor and edgecolor can be set in order to use different colors for the hatch and the background.

```
plt.hist(np.random.normal(size=500), bins=10, histtype='step', linewidth=2, facecolor='c', 
         hatch='/', edgecolor='k',fill=True)
```

This generates the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`histtype='step'`draws step lines. They are by definition not filled (because they are lines.

Instead, use `histtype='bar'` (which is the default, so you may equally leave it out completely).

Comment: Thank you. I found that `histtype='stepfilled'` also did the trick.